# IgnorePkg doesn't work for gvim and vim-runtime package

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I use a modified vim in Arch Linux, so I blocked gvim and vim-runtime from upgrading:

In /etc/pacman.conf I have:

`IgnorePkg = gvim , vim-runtime, vim, ...`

But when I do `pacman -Syu`, it still checks if gvim could be upgraded:

```
looking for inter-conflicts...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: gvim: requires vim-runtime=7.4.86-1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IgnorePkg` is supposed to be space separated, not comma separated. I suspect this may be what is causing the issue:

```
IgnorePkg=gvim vim-runtime vim
```